# action name with hyphens in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

I want to be able to call a page the in following way:

www.mydomain.com/articles/article-name-with-hyphens

I tries the following:

```
public class ArticlesController : Controller
{
    [ActionName("article-name-with-hyphens")]
    public ActionResult ArticleNameWithoutHyphens()
    {
        return View("~/Content/Views/Articles/ArticleNameWithoutHyphens.cshtml");
    }
}
```

However, I receive this message:

> The view '~/Content/Views/Articles/ArticleNameWithoutHyphens.cshtml'
>   or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched
>   locations. The following locations were searched:
>   ~/Content/Views/Articles/ArticleNameWithoutHyphens.cshtml

P.S. If I change the code to the regular way:

```
public class ArticlesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ArticleNameWithoutHyphens()
    {
        return View("~/Content/Views/Articles/ArticleNameWithoutHyphens.cshtml");
    }
}
```

And call:

> www.mydomain.com/articles/ArticleNameWithoutHyphens

I get the desired page.

Where is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with [Route](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/) attribute?

```
[RoutePrefix("Articles")]
public class ArticlesController : Controller
{
    [Route("article-name-with-hyphens")]
    public ActionResult ArticleNameWithoutHyphens()
    {
        return View("~/Content/Views/Articles/ArticleNameWithoutHyphens.cshtml");
    }
}
```

Therefore you can query like -

```
localhost/MyApp/Articles/article-name-with-hyphens
```

This perfectly works with MVC5.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it and got this: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Comment: which version of MVC you are using and what url you hit?

Comment: I see that I my target version is 4.5.1. This is strange because when I add new controller I actually add MVC 5 controller.

Comment: 4.5.1 is probably the .net framework you are working under. There shall be version 5.2.3 in web.config file if you have any. 
or the simpler step is to just right click on `system.web.mvc` reference in your references and click properties. There you get current version. 
Also, What is the url you hit?

Comment: system.web.mvc's version is 5.2.2.0. I hit the url: http://localhost:34546/articles/article-name-with-hyphens